# Underline TLabel with other color

Tags: delphi, underline, tlabel, delphi-12-athens

I have a `TLabel` on my form that is black and underlined, but I want the underlined color to be different than the normal color.

How can I do this?

I want the text to be black, but the underline to be red.

I've looked through all the properties, but I can't see it. Is this possible?

Comment: There is no native way to get a different color for the underline. You will have to subclass the Label and draw it manually

Comment: It can't exist, since `.Font.Style = [fsUnderline]` and `.Font.Color` are both bound to... well... the font. What were your attempts to achieve this? How do you expect this can exist? Have you seen what you want in a different program/window you could have screencaptured into your Q?

Comment: No Windows app ever has done this, AFAIK, and it is certainly not part of any standard Windows font, which means if you want it to happen you're going to need to do it yourself, as you've been told in other similar questions.

Comment: There are several 3rd party label components that allow HTML code. I don't know whehter this would allow the underline to have a different color than the text, though (otherwise I would have made this an answer, not a comment).

Comment: @dummzeuch HTML does not allow the underline to use a different color, but CSS does via the `text-decoration-color` property. But I haven't seen many (or any) UI controls that support *both* HTML *and* CSS, usually they support only HTML.

Comment: Placing another TLabel or TStaticText over the underlined label could be a workaround